# What is openssl_decrypt in Python?

Tags: python, php, openssl

I can't seem to do this PHP code in python:

```
openssl_decrypt( $acipher, "aes-256-gcm", $secret, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $bnonce, $tag);
```

This is my Python code:

```
from crypto.Cipher import AES
cipher = AES.new(acipher, AES.MODE_GCM, acipher)
plaintext = cipher.decrypt(secret)
# i don't even know where to put the "$bnonce, $tag", haha.
```

I'm quite stuck, please help.

I tried this but i got MAC check failed

```
secret              = "b34f09fc80e7974a918b50cfda6f48ce" # after i use open-ssl on some string, this is what i received. Just for Extra Info.
content             = "EZrjXFQ4o3oCVzy28q/IWYLgg9aP+VlmhQZ+wKs4C20D7k+lZMKlmi9UgZgINz6t/ucWmOzRFLo5DAZ3b6dYrMOz1lV2gJs9v9K6MDFeweREKRDupnTDKgx8AS7OaimofNK8wKxNp5QDnYBZNpY6BQ02mU5586LXGfwJJrAc3S7D85cZZofnUBpNcUztrHYOjCEtvB24p6j8W9ju3ALkAfd1Dk+UdKMVzp9sLa/qbzxPqQeZhPPS43A5b9Wa10DeKvMnMl4Z46M6j+AeudKmS46xCOM84zMbOonxIkCA+kS0BCPaDlpwOyiL31yeJqHw/dKhHuY0qVyHWgrlf3mdHizGKakeAoYsy4Wo1WjeTteSRnw713s="

# Content
bcontent                            = str( base64.b64decode(content) )
bcontent_total_characters           = len(bcontent)
bcontent_total_characters_minus_12  = bcontent_total_characters - 12
bnonce                              = bcontent[ bcontent_total_characters_minus_12 : bcontent_total_characters - 12 + bcontent_total_characters ]
bcipher                             = bcontent[ 0 : 0 + bcontent_total_characters_minus_12 ]
# default tag
bcipher_total_characters            = len(bcipher)
taglength                           = 16
tag                                 = bcipher[ bcipher_total_characters - taglength : bcipher_total_characters - taglength + bcipher_total_characters ]
acipher                             = bcipher[ 0 : 0 + bcipher_total_characters - taglength]

cipher = AES.new(str.encode(secret), AES.MODE_GCM,  str.encode(bnonce) )
decrypted = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(str.encode(content), str.encode(tag))
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/eoli3n/d6d862feb71102588867516f3b34fef1). I use similar with slight modifications. just note that the code uses AES-256-CBC and you are using AES-GCM

Comment: #chidimez, can you please share the exact code in my case?

Answer (score 1):

From php documentation i modified your function vars you can rename them if you like

```
openssl_decrypt( $acipher,
             "aes-256-gcm",
             $passphrase, //This is your secret
             OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
             $iv, //This is your nonce
             $tag //This is your tag
);
```

This is how it would look in python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# pip install pycryptodome

import json

from base64 import b64encode,b64decode

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes


from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes


def python_encrypt(data, passphrase, iv):
    """
         Encrypt using AES-256-GCM 
    """

    cipher = AES.new(passphrase, AES.MODE_GCM,iv)
    ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)
    json_k = [ 'nonce', 'ciphertext', 'tag' ]

    json_v = [ b64encode(x).decode('utf-8') for x in [cipher.nonce, ciphertext, tag ]]

    result = json.dumps(dict(zip(json_k, json_v))) 
   
    return result
    
    
def python_decrypt(data, passphrase, iv, tag):
    """
         Decrypt using AES-256-GCM 
    """
    
    cipher = AES.new(passphrase, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)

    decrypted = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(data, tag)
 
    return decrypted

#Testing code out
data = b"secret"   
passphrase = get_random_bytes(16)
nonce = get_random_bytes(16)

enc_json = python_encrypt(data,passphrase,nonce)

print(enc_json)

b64 = json.loads(enc_json)

json_k = [ 'nonce', 'ciphertext', 'tag' ]

jv = {k:b64decode(b64[k]) for k in json_k}


print(python_decrypt(jv['ciphertext'], passphrase, jv['nonce'], jv['tag']))
```

Modified from the [docs](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#gcm-mode)

Comment: Can you please check my code? i got MAC issue. Not sure what i did wrong. It failed on this part: "decrypted = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(str.encode(content), str.encode(tag))" –

Comment: Your secret should probably be converted to binary using binascii.unhexlify as it seems to be a hex, similar conversions may apply to nonce depending on how you encoded the data. you should also check how you generate your nonce and tag  because i believe openssl defaults to 16 if you don't explicitly set it, You seem to be using 12 for your nonce. I can only guess at this point. i'll need to see a sample of how you implemented openssl_encrypt.